# How to register the custom SSL certificate of X509TrustManager in Jboss AS7

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x

Is there anybody to know how to register a custom SSL certificate of X509TrustManager in Jboss 7?

As the requirement of my project, I need to customize the default behavior of SSL certificate on X509TrustManager. I already have a custom certificate by extending X509TrustManager and override the default behavior, but now I do not know to register this custom file that Jboss AS7 can understand my own file instead of default X509TrustManager.

```
public class MyManager implements com.sun.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
     public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) { return true; }
     public boolean isHostTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) { return true; }
     ...
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a security domain you can change the behavior of the Trust Manager in this way:

```xml
<security-domain name="CertificateDomain">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="CertificateRoles" flag="required">
            <module-option name="securityDomain" value="CertificateDomain"/>
            <module-option name="verifier" value="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.AnyCertVerifier"/>
            ....
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <jsse keystore-password="..." keystore-url=".." truststore-password="..." truststore-url="..."  truststore-provider="..."/>
</security-domain>
```

`truststore-provider` Provider of the truststore. The default JDK provider for the truststore type is used if this attribute is null

[Security subsystem configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Security+subsystem+configuration)

Another way is to add the file standalone.xml the following properties (not tested)

```xml
<system-properties>
     <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider" value="..."/>
<system-properties>
```

Comment: Where can I put my custom X509TrustManager? <system-properties>
     <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider" value="X509TrustManager"/>
<system-properties>

Comment: Take a look in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores